# Javascript: Browser-based XML tree editor

Tags: javascript, xml

Is there an XML tree-structure editor that runs in the browser?

In other words, a browser-based app that takes an XML string, represents it as a visual tree structure, lets me add/delete/change elements of the tree, and then reserialize it back to an XML string?

The more mimimalist, the better!

Answer (score 3):

There is jsTree - I don't know if that's what you're looking for here. http://www.jstree.com/demo

But it will be able to render an xml tree structure as well as create, move, and delete nodes. The problem is saving it to your .xml file.

The way I attempted acknowledging when an action was taken (like creating an element node) and responding by creating is in my actual file.

If this is something of what you want let me know and I can paste some of my code here.

Comment: Did you stumble upon any other library since you last answered this one? A library which easily handles rendering xml as tree and then saving the tree back as xml?

Comment: I know this post is cold but would love to see your code if you are still active and willing to share. I have to do something like this and would love to see an example illustrated. thanks